# Passing list into another list

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Suppose I have a zero matrix `Amat` and a list of values `ltest` that contains the values of the matrix `Amat` for the some of its diagonal elements:

```
L = 10000;
Amat = 0. IdentityMatrix[L];
ltest = {{-0.70710, 1329}, {-0.25, 5607}, {-0.3535, 1261}, {-0.25, 4393}, {-0.5, 4358},
{-0.3511, 1009}, {-1., 3815}, {-0.25, 3784}, {-0.133, 3667}, {-0.88, 909}};
```

Now in order to pass the second column of `ltest` to `Amat` I can do:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[ltest], i++, Amat[[ltest[[All, 2]][[i]], ltest[[All, 2]][[i]]]] = ltest[[All, 1]][[i]]]
```

Is there a shorter way without using `For`?

Comment: Have you already tried looking at `SparseArray[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
L = 10000;
ltest = {{-0.70710, 1329}, {-0.25, 5607}, {-0.3535, 1261}, {-0.25, 
    4393}, {-0.5, 4358}, {-0.3511, 1009}, {-1., 3815}, {-0.25, 
    3784}, {-0.133, 3667}, {-0.88, 909}};
Amat = SparseArray[{#2, #2} -> #1 & @@@ ltest, {L, L}, 0]
```

And `Amat` can be used as an ordinary matrix.

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Amat = SparseArray[{#[[2]], #[[2]]} -> #[[1]] & /@ ltest, {L, L}, 0]`?

Comment: @MelaGo Yes you are right.@SneezeFor16Min please edit your post

Comment: @MelaGo Thanks for pointing that out! I misread OP's code... Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

With `L` and `ltest` as given in the OP, here is another way to use `SparseArray[]`:

```
DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Rule @@@ Reverse[ltest, 2], L]]
```

`DiagonalMatrix[]` is smart enough to return a `SparseArray[]` when fed a diagonal represented as a `SparseArray[]`.

Comment: Smart! This is ~1.6x faster than using straight-forward `Rule`s for reasons I don't know.

Comment: can it be used if the elements of `Amat` are not diagonal, i.e `ltest = {{-0.70710, 5, 1329}, {-0.25, 31,5607}, {-0.3535, 411,1261}, {-0.25,706, 4393}, {-0.5,58, 4358},
{-0.3511, 2871,1009}, {-1.,7415, 3815}, {-0.25,1254, 3784}, {-0.133, 33,3667}, {-0.88, 17,909}};` where the last two elements are the `i,j` indices of `Amat`?

Comment: @geom, then you use `SparseArray[]` directly, as I originally advised you in my comment to your question. Try it out, and if you get stuck, [ask a new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @J.M. thanks, no need to ask a new question, `SparseArray[]` works fine